# Latex: Different pages with different margins

Tags: templates, latex, document, margins

I'm making a latex template for a document type to use at work. For that document, I have two different "commands" one to make the title page; and other to make the rest of the document.

The margins that I need in the title page are different from the ones in the rest of the document. Because of that I have some "\setlength" commands for the title page and other for the rest.

The problem is that when I compile the document, the different margins only take effect 1 page after the one they were supposed to. For example, if I want a page for the title page and the rest of the document different, what happens is that the 1st page has the title margins, the 2nd has the title margins (and shouldn't) and from the 3rd page onwards the margins are correct for the rest of the document.

What am I doing wrong?

Can you tell me what would be your strategy for making a document like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might get better/faster/more focused responses at [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Of course, you might not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `geometry` package.  You can then use `\newgeometry` in order to change the layout mid-document.  This command also does a `clearpage`, so you should put it exactly where you want the page break.